# xslt gmuenchian grouping with sub-groups

Tags: xslt, key, muenchian-grouping

I am trying to re-structure xml data into groups and sub-group. I was able to get it to work, but my code has to include something, that looks (at least to me) like a workaround. Here are my sample files:

Data.xml:

```
<data>
    <record Group="g1" SubGroup="sg1">Record 1</record>
    <record Group="g2" SubGroup="sg1">Record 2</record>
    <record Group="g1" SubGroup="sg1">Record 3</record>
    <record Group="g2" SubGroup="sg1">Record 4</record>
    <record Group="g2" SubGroup="sg2">Record 5</record>
    <record Group="g1" SubGroup="sg2">Record 6</record>
</data>
```

Stylesheet.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:key name="Group"    match="record" use="@Group" />
    <xsl:key name="SubGroup" match="record" use="@SubGroup" />

    <xsl:template match="/data">
        <xsl:variable name="Records" select="record"/>

        <data>
            <xsl:for-each select="$Records[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('Group',@Group)[1])]">
                <xsl:sort select="@Group"/>
                <xsl:variable name="Group" select="@Group"/>

                <xsl:call-template name="Group">
                    <xsl:with-param name="Records" select="$Records[@Group = $Group]"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="Group" select="$Group"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </data>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="Group">
        <xsl:param name="Records"/>
        <xsl:param name="Group"/>

        <group name="{$Group}">
            <xsl:for-each select="$Records[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('SubGroup',@SubGroup)[1])]">
<!-- this works:    <xsl:for-each select="$Records[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('SubGroup',@SubGroup)[@Group = $Group][1])]"> -->
                <xsl:sort select="@SubGroup"/>
                <xsl:variable name="SubGroup" select="@SubGroup"/>

                <xsl:call-template name="SubGroup">
                    <xsl:with-param name="Records" select="$Records[@SubGroup = $SubGroup]"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="Group" select="$Group"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="SubGroup" select="$SubGroup"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="SubGroup">
        <xsl:param name="Records"/>
        <xsl:param name="Group"/>
        <xsl:param name="SubGroup"/>

        <subgroup name="{$SubGroup}">
            <xsl:for-each select="$Records">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </subgroup>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the output generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <group name="g1">
    <subgroup name="sg1">
      <record Group="g1" SubGroup="sg1">Record 1</record>
      <record Group="g1" SubGroup="sg1">Record 3</record>
    </subgroup>
  </group>
  <group name="g2">
    <subgroup name="sg2">
      <record Group="g2" SubGroup="sg2">Record 5</record>
    </subgroup>
  </group>
</data>
```

but this is the output, I want to have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <group name="g1">
    <subgroup name="sg1">
      <record Group="g1" SubGroup="sg1">Record 1</record>
      <record Group="g1" SubGroup="sg1">Record 3</record>
    </subgroup>
    <subgroup name="sg2">
      <record Group="g1" SubGroup="sg2">Record 6</record>
    </subgroup>
  </group>
  <group name="g2">
    <subgroup name="sg1">
      <record Group="g2" SubGroup="sg1">Record 2</record>
      <record Group="g2" SubGroup="sg1">Record 4</record>
    </subgroup>
    <subgroup name="sg2">
      <record Group="g2" SubGroup="sg2">Record 5</record>
    </subgroup>
  </group>
</data>
```

The problem is the for-each loop in the tempalte named "Group". It seems, that the key()-function is not working on the nodes contained in $Records but on the entire input XML file.

I get identical results with xsltproc and with saxon, so I do not think, it is a bug in my xslt processor. It seems, that I did not completely understand, how key() works.

If I add an additional selector `[@Group = $Group]` to key()'s output, I get the expected result.

Can somebody explain what is going on and why the additional selector `[@Group = $Group]` is needed.

Mario

Comment: Same issue is solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793149/xslt-template-doesnt-apply-on-direct-child-nodes/39793718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to do sub-grouping, you need to use a concatenated key of both the main group and the sub-group

```
 <xsl:key name="SubGroup" match="record" use="concat(@Group,'|', @SubGroup)" />
```

Then, just use it in the same way as before, with the concatenation

```
<xsl:for-each select="$Records[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('SubGroup',concat(@Group,'|', @SubGroup))[1])]">
```

Try this XSLT (which I have also simplified to utilise the key when calling your named templates with the records)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:key name="Group"    match="record" use="@Group" />
    <xsl:key name="SubGroup" match="record" use="concat(@Group,'|', @SubGroup)" />

    <xsl:template match="/data">
        <data>
            <xsl:for-each select="record[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('Group',@Group)[1])]">
                <xsl:sort select="@Group"/>

                <xsl:call-template name="Group">
                    <xsl:with-param name="Records" select="key('Group',@Group)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </data>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="Group">
        <xsl:param name="Records"/>

        <group name="{@Group}">
            <xsl:for-each select="$Records[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('SubGroup',concat(@Group,'|', @SubGroup))[1])]">
                <xsl:sort select="@SubGroup"/>

                <xsl:call-template name="SubGroup">
                    <xsl:with-param name="Records" select="key('SubGroup',concat(@Group,'|', @SubGroup))"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="SubGroup">
        <xsl:param name="Records"/>
        <subgroup name="{@SubGroup}">
            <xsl:for-each select="$Records">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </subgroup>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Your usage of key and concat() and key() to select the parameter is really cool. But I still do not understand, why I have to consider @Group in the inner loop, since `$Records` already has been reduced to only include records of the current group.

Comment: @MarioKlebsch Because as you have correctly surmised, keys (in XSLT 1.0) work across the entire document.

Comment: @michael.hor257k As you said, I summarized it correctly, but until now, I was not aware of it. Thank you very much.